# How to LEFT JOIN on mysql rows that don't exist past a certain year?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, I'll list table names and relevant fields:

```
PLAYERS:
playerid

STATS:
statsid
playerid
year
```

Every time a player accumulated stats in a game, it put a row in the `stats` table and recorded the year.

Now, I would like get a list of all players in the `players` table who have NOT recorded any stats in 2016 and up.

I tried LEFT JOIN but don't really understand what I'm doing and couldn't get it to work.  This is one of the things I tried, don't laugh

```
SELECT * FROM `players` LEFT JOIN `stats` ON players.playerid = stats.playerid where count(*) = 0 and stats.year >= 2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't know the [exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) grammar, eg:

```
select * 
from players p 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from stats s 
                  where s.playerid = p.playerid
                    and s.year >= 2016)
```

shows players who do not exist in the stats table for those years, easy to understand and remember.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the EXISTS grammar, just read up on it and it's working just as I needed, thanks very much for the knowledge.